# FCP 7 swap in externally edited audio track

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro

In Final Cut Pro 7, I've edited together a scene, using the original audio recordings from the video files.  However, after doing so, I realized that I needed to edit the audio using an external program.

I opened the audio from the original video files and have them saved as separate .wav files now, of the same length.  However, at this point I am uncertain how to "swap in" the new audio for the old audio.

The problem is that I don't just want to replace one section in the timeline, but I want to replace *every* section in the timeline which refers to a given clip, and I want it to sample the *new* audio file from exactly the same places it sampled the old one.

That is, I want to edit it so that it behaves as if I replaced the audio in the video file *before* I did anything with FCP.

I really don't want to be manually aligning the audio.

Comment: To improve your workflow, you can also try exporting an XML for your sequence. I don't know what audio editor you use but probably they have such a capability to import sequences from different editing softwares. This way you can edit just the needed parts of your audio files and export a single file to replace your whole audio.

Answer (score 1):

*This is dependant on the new .wav files having a similar waveform as the originals. If you have changed them a lot then the method below wont work!*

---

**You will need to get a copy of [Plural Eyes](http://www.singularsoftware.com/pluraleyes.html) for Final Cut**. Plural Eyes is a 3rd party program that syncs audio. I use the program alot to auto sync externally recorded audio to video clips.

Plural Eyes has a feature where if you lock the video tracks, it wont move them around, so effectively you can sync and replace your reference audio with the .wav files:

> By default, PluralEyes will move the clips in the output sequence(s)
>   so that the earliest clip starts at time zero. But sometimes you want
>   one of the clips to stay in place and have the others move relative to
>   that one. **If you lock the track that contains that clip, PluralEyes
>   will not move it.**

They have a [how-to section for Final Cut 7](http://www.singularsoftware.com/howto_pe_finalcut.html) and [video tutorials](http://www.singularsoftware.com/tutorials.html) on their website.

Hope this helps!